# Magento 2 : Could not save admin form contents into the DB

Tags: magento2, adminform, uicomponent, save

I have added an admin form using Ui component.

example_example_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="example_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

example_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">example_form.example_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">example_form.example_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">example Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">example_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Edit\Button\Save</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Edit\Button\Back</item>        
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="example_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Example\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">example_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">example_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">example_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="module/example/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument> 
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="example_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">example [General]</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="openOnShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="example_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">label_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Title</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Model\Config\Source\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset> 

</form>
```

And in DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Example;

use Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Example\CollectionFactory;;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;  

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_loadedData;

    protected $storeManager;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $exampleCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->collection = $exampleCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }


    /**
    * Get data
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }

    return $this->_loadedData;
    }
}
```

save.php

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();


    if ($data) {    

        /** @var \Webspeaks\ProductsGrid\Model\Contact $model */
        $model = $this->moduleModel;

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('module_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }

        $model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved this item.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['module_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the label.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['module_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('module_id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

Not able to save this form. Please help..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following code in your execute function of Save Controller (Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Example/Save.php)

```
 public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if ($data) {
            try{
                $id = $data['id'];
                $customModel = $this->customModel->load($id);
                $data = array_filter($data, function($value) { return $value !== ''; });
                $customModel->setData($data);
                $customModel->save();

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Successfully saved the item.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);                
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {               
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData($data);
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $customModel->getId()]);
            }
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jancy. . it works.[$data = array_filter($data, function($value) { return $value !== ''; });]